# A query to the content of a OneNote page in Microsoft Graph returns a 10019 error

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

Some pages in one section fail API calls with a `500` error. The query URL is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/{page-id}/content
```

The response is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "10019",
    "message":
      "The service detected a request that exceeds the maximum recursive call limit and has aborted it.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "7514b9c5-ffc1-4cec-82c3-ceee523a8913",
      "date": "2018-04-12T08:21:04"
    }
  }
}
```

I can access the pages in the OneNote apps, and I'm fairly sure the API call is correct, as it works for pages which are virtually identical. The `10019` error code does not appear in the [troubleshooting documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/onenote_error_codes#codes-from-10001-to-19999).

An explanation of what's going on and how to mitigate it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the metadata for the page (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/{page-id}/)?

Comment: Yes I can. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Sorry Isaac we had flighted some new code which we have turned off for now. Can you check and confirm that you no longer get this error? Thanks!

Comment: That seems to have fixed it . Thanks

Comment: Same error happened

Comment: Is anyone checking on this, please?