# Onenote api. The service detected a request that exceeds the maximum recursive call limit and has aborted it

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I saw somebody already posted the same issue long before and he said it's fixed, but now I am facing the same problem.

> ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: 10019
>
> Message: The service detected a request that exceeds the maximum recursive call limit and has aborted it.

The issue seems to be reoccuring recently...
I hope someone in MS team catch this thread and start looking on this issue.
Thanks.

PS> I deleted the specific page ID as this is reported to proper person.

Comment: @ste
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791707/a-query-to-the-content-of-a-onenote-page-in-microsoft-graph-returns-a-10019-erro

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a known issue and the fix is on the way. Will reply back when it's done. Or you can re-try your request next week